# Nginx Config.json mount ConfigMap in k8s deployment Angular App

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, volume, configmap

I am trying to mount a ConfigMap into Nginx, but when I mount the ConfigMap my POD fails to start with the error `Error: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root`

My Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment 
metadata:   
   name: {{ template "fullname" . }}   
   namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}   
   labels:
     app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
     chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
     release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
     heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}" 
spec:   
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}   
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
      release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"     # We dont need a large deployment history limit as Helm keeps it's own   # history   revisionHistoryLimit: 2   template:
    metadata:
      namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
      labels:
        app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
        release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: container
        image: {{ template "docker-image" . }}
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["sleep", "15"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        # The port that our container listens for HTTP requests on. Might also
        # be 3000 or 8000
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
        env:
        # You can set environment variables that don't change across environments here
          - name: ACTIVE_ENVIRONMENT
            value: {{ .Values.environment }}
        volumeMounts:
        - name: msal-config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/html/assets/config.json
          subPath: config.json
          readOnly: true
        resources: {{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 10 }}
      imagePullSecrets: 
      - name: secret
      volumes:
      - name: msal-config-volume
        configMap:
          name: msal-configmap
```

My `/etc/nginx/html/assets/` is my deployment artificial, where I am trying to replace `config.json` file from ConfigMap. when I mount the `msal-config-volume` the pod fails to start.

Comment: I have resolved this issue, stuck on on this for 2 days!! will update the solution in the morning..

Comment: care to share the solution? :)